# Condition to check if exactactly 2 numbers in the Array of 3 elements are odd

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have `3` values in an array.

How can I write an `if` statement to check if `2` of the `3` numbers are odd to print a message?

Code:

```
int[] test = {1, 2, 3};        
        
if (test[0] % 2 != 0 && test[1] % 2 != 0 &&
    test[2] % 2 != 0) {
            
    System.out.println("All numbers  odd");
} 
else if (condition) { //what will go here as a condition
    System.out.println("2 numbers odd");
}
```

So what can be used to check if `2` out of `3` numbers are *odd*?

Comment: Odd numbers have their lowest bit set. Add them together and if the sum is 2, you know two of three were odd. `((test[0] & 1) + (test[1] & 1) + (test[2] & 1)) == 2`

Comment: you can also use streams `long oddCount = Arrays.stream(test).filter(n -> n % 2 == 1).count();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very straightforward approach would be to count the number of *odd* element in the loop and then pass the number into a condition.

That's how it can be done in a concise way using Java 14 [*switch expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] test = {1, 2, 3};
    
    int oddCount = 0;
    
    for (int next : test) {
        if (next % 2 != 0) oddCount++;
    }
    
    switch (oddCount) {
        case 1 -> System.out.println("1 number is odd");
        case 2 -> System.out.println("2 numbers are odd");
        case 3 -> System.out.println("All numbers are odd");
    }
}
```

Another way is to obtain a total of these numbers.

If exactly `2` of these `3` numbers are **odd**, it means that their *sum* should be **even**.

So it will be sufficient to check whether the *sum* is *even* and at least one of the first `2` array elements is *odd*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int[] test = {1, 2, 3};
    
    long sum = 0; // sum is of type `long` to guard against `int` overflow
    
    for (int next : test) {
        sum += next;
    }        
    
    if (sum % 2 != 0 && test[0] % 2 != 0 && test[1] % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("All numbers are odd");
    }
    else if (sum % 2 == 0 && (test[0] % 2 != 0 || test[1] % 2 != 0)) {
        System.out.println("2 numbers are odd");
    }
    else if (sum % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("1 number is odd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
int[] test = {1, 2, 3};

switch (IntStream.of(test).map(i -> i & 1).sum()) {
    case 3: System.out.println("All numbers odd"); break;
    case 2: System.out.println("2 numbers odd"); break;
}
```

output:

```
2 numbers odd
```

Answer (score 0):

So first we will be calculating all the possible scenarios :

1. All even
2. All odd
3. 1 odd (2 even)
4. 2 odd (1 even)

Then we use intStream functions to calculate the number of odds and even.

```
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     int[] test = {2,5,3};
        
        if (IntStream.of(test).noneMatch(num -> num % 2 == 0)) // All odd
        {
            System.out.println("All numbers odd");
        }
        else if (IntStream.of(test).noneMatch(num -> num % 2 == 1)) // All even
        {
            System.out.println("All numbers even");
        }
        else if(IntStream.of(test).sum()%2==1)
        {
            System.out.println("1 number is odd");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("2 numbers are odd");
        }
    }
}
```